# Create an alias to a command that has spaces in it

Tags: powershell, alias

My use case is to create an alias for opening Firefox. Usually I used `Start-Process firefox.exe`, which is fine. I would like, though, to just type `xfirefox` instead. Here is what I have tried:

Quotes

```
Shaun> set-alias xfirefox "Start-Process firefox.exe"
Shaun> xfirefox
xfirefox : The term 'Start-Process firefox.exe' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program...
```

Curlies

```
Shaun> set-alias xfirefox { Start-Process firefox.exe }
Set-Alias : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Value' because its 
argument is specified as a script block and there is no
input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Aliases are just that - aliases for command names - not command names plus arguments.  What you want is a function e.g.:

```
function xfirefox {
    Start-Process firefox.exe $args
}
```

Then you could launch like so:

```
xfirefox
xfirefox http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Don't you need `-ArgumentList` with a quoted list of arguments if there are spaces?

Comment: I did `function t {ng e --devServerTarget=}` then I just launched `t` and it still returns an error `t : The term 'ng e --devServerTarget=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: and how can I add this function to powershell permanently?

Comment: Add that function to your profile (startup) script.